# Swedish characters in Go Lang

Tags: string, go

The following function does not work with Swedish characters, i.e `å/Å/ä/Ä/ö/Ö`.

```
func StartsWithUppercase(s string) bool {
    return (string(s[0]) == strings.ToUpper(string(s[0])))
}
```

How do I proceed to check if a string starts with upper case Swedish character?

```
w := "åÅäÄöÖ"
for i := 0; i < len(w); i++ {
    fmt.Println(i, w[i])
}
```

Results in:

```
 1. 195 
 2. 165
 3. 195
 4. 133
 5. 195 
 6. 164
 7. 195
 8. 132
 9. 195
 10. 182 
 11. 195
 12. 150
```

Comment: I believe [unicode.IsUpper()](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsUpper) would be useful for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indexing a `string` indexes its bytes not its *runes* (a [`rune`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals) is a unicode codepoint).

What you want to do is check the first character (`rune`) of the `string`, not its first byte in its UTF-8 encoded form. And for this there is support in the standard library: [`unicode.IsUpper()`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsUpper).

To get the first `rune`, you can convert the `string` to a slice of runes, and take the first element (at index 0).

```
ins := []string{
    "å/Å/ä/Ä/ö/Ö",
    "Å/ä/Ä/ö/Ö"}

for _, s := range ins {
    fmt.Println(s, unicode.IsUpper([]rune(s)[0]))
}
```

Output:

```
å/Å/ä/Ä/ö/Ö false
Å/ä/Ä/ö/Ö true
```

Comment: `[]rune(s)` converts the whole string; you can extract only the first character with something like http://play.golang.org/p/OmOv3SMPu4 . (Though indexing gets bytes, `range`ing over the string decodes the UTF-8 to get runes.)

Comment: I should have said "you can extract only the first *code point*," not "the first character." The notion of "characters" in Unicode is extra complicated thanks to combining marks, nonprintable things like the RTL direction mark, and so on. For many purposes the first rune is fine, though.

Comment: @twotwotwo Yes, `range` is a faster way to get the first rune. Since the question contained short strings, converting to a `rune` slice is simpler. For long strings the `range` should be used or [`utf8.DecodeRune()`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRune) or [`utf8.DecodeRuneInString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRuneInString).